# How to forward requests to a local ip without router(modem) portforwarding

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

i just created a local web system in asp.net and use IIS express 8 to host it on my laptop,
then i forward port 9090 to my laptop ip 192.168.1.104, and it works great.
So the problem is here that when i go to another network for example to my friends house , i have to forward port 9090 to my laptop ip in their router. so i wonder that is any way to do this work without getting into router and write a application in c# to this work for me??
Its so good to have my local website running in all networks when i get an ip from them.
and i think its possible cause sql server did it some how, you know if you got a database in sql server you can access that database with [serverIP]:1433 without forwarding port 1433 to server ip in router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys i just found solution by myself and wanna share with you , i just use this link http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP

and its about referencing to NATUPNPLib from com tab in VS, and use code below to do my work

for getting list of ported ip-ports

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
foreach (NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMapping portMapping in mappings)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(portMapping.Description + "-" + portMapping.ExternalIPAddress +
    "_" + portMapping.ExternalPort + "-" + portMapping.InternalClient + "-" + 
    portMapping.InternalPort + "-" + portMapping.Protocol);
 }
```

for saving port

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Add(9090, "TCP", 9090, "192.168.1.104", true, "proapp");
```

for removing port

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNAT();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Remove(9090, "TCP");
```